# Regular Expressions for extracting Correlation Parameters in IBM RPT

Tags: regex, correlation, extract, rpt

I have a problem here. The line in response goes something like this:

```
*14*PerfTest1 PerfTest2*14*Individual
```

Here I want to extract out `PerfTest2` for a LastName value.

But the first name also would differ for some test data. `*14*Individual` would be the same for all the responses. Need help in extracting `PerfTest2` from similar lines like above.

Comment: If I get you right, you could do it with `\w+(?=\*14\*Individual)`. [Check this example](https://regex101.com/r/tR5wJ9/1). But some more input/output examples wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But the same does not work in RPT Reference Element. It says Unclosed Group near Index

Comment: Did you copy right after I entered comment? Because I missed the closing `)` and edited 20 seconds later...

Comment: Do you know anything about regex flavor? Because I've been googling to find info on RPT regex, but can hardly find anything...

Comment: I am also trying hard to find the actual regex. None of the above works. '\w(.+?)\*14\*Individual' should also work. But sadly it doesn't

Comment: The how about   \*14\*\w+\s+(.*)\*14\*Individual   ?  It will put the name in the first capture group, But since it doesn't use lookahead nor lookbehind it matches the whole string.